# jQuery: mouseover on a background div "through" a foreground tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background div and a foreground div which fades in as the background is moused over, and fades out when the background is mousd out.

But when the foreground fades in, it steals focus from the background and the tooltip ends up "flashing":

http://jsfiddle.net/ts97t/

How do I keep the tooltip visible and stop the flashing?

Thanks

Comment: Your red box is in front of the background, therefore it does react that way. For a tooltip, better use http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/01/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mouse over me.
      This needs to stay visible, and not flash, until I mouse out of the green square!

JQUERY

```
$("#background").hover(function(){
 $("#tooltip").fadeIn();
},function(){
    $("#tooltip").fadeOut();
   });​
```

and if you want #tooltip overlaps the "**Mouse over me**" text.

```
#tooltip {
    display: none;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    background: red;
    top:0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/ts97t/4/)

second way

```
   var i=0;
$("#background").hover(function(){
     $("#tooltip").fadeIn();
    },function(){
        if (i==1) {
            $("#tooltip").fadeOut();
i=0;
        } 
    });

$('#tooltip').hover('',function(){
  i=1;

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="background">Mouse over me.</div>
<div id="tooltip">This needs to stay visible, and not flash, until I mouse out of the green square!</div>
```

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ts97t/11/)

Comment: A little lacking in explanation as to what you've changed for him, but a good answer +1. @WackGet Please look [here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for info on the `.hover()` functionality which afshin has hadded to your jquery.

Comment: In my real application I'm actually hovering over an image map <area> tag, so I can't actually put content inside it. The tooltip element is entirely separate within the markup and often appears outside the area of the image map. Thanks, though. Any ideas?

Comment: I Edit my answer take look at the second way

Comment: Thank you - I tried it the second way also, but it still flashes for me when I wiggle the mouse. I'm using Firefox 15.

Comment: It's really driving me crazy. :)

Comment: I check it with chorme works fine but with IE 9 still blinking

Comment: You're right. Chrome works fine. For the first time I am angry with Firefox. It's as bad as IE in this case. Do you think anything can be done?

Comment: In Firefox I still see the flicker. Sorry! I think this one has defeated us. I might make a new post with a clearer explanation. Thanks so much for trying though.